# SIP video/audio tanscoding using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, sip

Is it possible to integrate ffmpeg with SIP server(open sip) and SIP client(lin_phone)? When sip phone_A tries to video call sip phone_B, can this video call be transrated using ffmpeg? What if i capture the RTP packet using wireshark,then use videosnarf tool to extract raw rtp stream ,then transrate it using FFmpeg and then send it to SIP phone B? Can the SIP phone B able to identify the stream?

Comment: yes it is possible. Unfortunately your question is too broad

Comment: why is my question too broad! i need to design accordingly if the above mentioned is possible.